# Bot is getting stuck at "Download Dependencies" in A360

Tags: automationanywhere

Automation Anywhere A360 BOT stuck in downloading dependencies, whenever I try to run the bot in dev server.

What I have tried:

1. Re-installing the Bot Agent with Admin role.
2. Restarting the Bot Agent Service and preloading the packages.
3. Stopping the Bot Agent Service and renaming the Global Cache Folder to some other name. Then Again starting the Bot Agent.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I see this issue and I have remove the device from within the control room devices list, clear the global cache and then run through the device connection process again.